# How to call ajax recursively until a certain condition becomes true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, recursion

I am trying to call an ajax method recursively until `maxnumId` is empty or undefined. My current code only fires one time! Could any one tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

This is the code:

```
<script>
    var maxnumId = null;

    function callApi4() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.somesite.com/ddddd" + ( maxnumId ? "&max_id=" + maxnumId : ""),
            success: function(data) {
                maxnumId = data.pagination.next_max_id;
                alert('maxnumId is now: ' + maxnumId);
                document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data.pagination.next_max_id+'\n' ;

            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

            $(".content").append("<img class='image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low.url +"' />");   
            }

              if(maxnumId != "undefined"){
                setTimeout(callApi4(), 2000);
               }
               else
               {
                 alert('finished');
               }
            }
        });
    }
    </script>

<button onclick="callApi4()">call ajax first time</button>
```

Comment: Are you actually looking for the string "undefined" or for an actual undefined value of maxnumId in your if?  If you're looking for an undefined value, then you'll need to drop the quotation marks.

If that's not the issue, what output are you getting back from the server?

Comment: Although my comment above may not help the original problem...  Looking at the logic I would expect that to give you infinite callbacks.  What output are you actually getting?

Comment: thanks for replies. When i run the function first time i get one set of data which is from first api call. Then i dont get any data back from server! i was expecting that after first call of function via button the api get called until i get empty data for maxnumId ! but even after placing alert inside if and else statement that makes recursive call ,the alerts never get poped up! so i think my recursive call is not working !

Comment: Yeah, I think EduardoFernandes actually has the right answer for you.  When you have parentheses on the timeout call, it's not actually passing in the function, but its return value.  If you start getting an infinite loop after that, then my undefined suggestion might be the problem at that point.

Comment: i dont get any infinite loop! the ajax only get called once which is via button click and rest of ajax call should be done using settimeout but it never calls the ajax again!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `setTimeout(callApi4(), 2000);` write `setTimeout(callApi4, 2000);`, removing the parenthesis from the callApi4 method.

Comment: i even tried that . i even placed setTimeout(callApi4, 2000); outside if statement still ajax never get called and i got no response!

Comment: Put it outside of the loop. It is not being called because the code break somewhere else. You must have a null property which you are trying to access a property.

Comment: I believe you have null objects, either here `maxnumId = data.pagination.next_max_id;` or here `document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data.pagination.next_max_id+'\n' ;``because there are simply too many objects which can be null. Either use console.log or alerts to check it.

Comment: Quick tip: in `<button onclick="callApi4()">call ajax first time</button>` add a semi-column after callApi4(), which results in: `<button onclick="callApi4();">call ajax first time</button>`